# pandas dataframe with comma separated string entries, change to unique comma separated entries

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe as such:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [["a,a,a", "b,b", "c,c,c"], ["d,d","e","fd"],["g,h,i", "g", "fg,h,a"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["ColA","ColB","ColC"])

df

    ColA    ColB    ColC
0   a,a,a   b,b     c,c,c
1   d,d     e       fd
2   g,h,i   g       fg,h,a
```

I would like to reformat this table to:

```
    colA    colB    colC  
0   a       b       c
1   d       e       fd
2   g,h,i   g       fg,h,a
```

So unique entries after string splitting each entry by comma separated value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.applymap(lambda elements: ','.join(set(elements.split(','))))
```

`applymap()` applies a function to all elements (cells) of a dataframe. The lambda function here first splits the data by `,`, then creates a [set](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) of all elements and concatenates them back with [strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) `.join()` method.

Comment: very nice use of `applymap`